# PHP MySQL PDO Login / Registration system over PBKDF2 Encryption won't log in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo, pbkdf2

I am working with a specific encryption ( **PBKDF2** ) for some reasons.
I am now building the website and I am having an issue with the Log In system.
The Registration page works perfectly has desired.

I don't have any output of errors when I try to log in and still the password does not match.

Here is my ***registration.php*** :

```
<?php
require '../global.php';
$pdo = New Database();
$account->IPisBanned($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$account->isConnected();

if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['password']) AND !empty($_POST['password_confirmation'])) {
    $bdd = $pdo->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?', [$core->F_HTML($_POST['username'])]);
    if($bdd->rowCount() == 0) {
        if(preg_match('`^([a-zA-Z0-9-=?!@]{3,15})$`', $core->F_HTML($_POST['username']))) {
            $bdd2 = $pdo->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?', [$core->F_HTML($_POST['email'])]);
            if($bdd2->rowCount() == 0) {
                if(filter_var($core->F_HTML($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {

                        if(strlen($_POST['password']) >= 6 AND strlen($_POST['password_confirmation']) >= 6) {

                            $iterations = 10000;
                            $length = 40;
                            $secret = "at_least_16_byte";
                            $salt = $secret.$_POST['username'];
                            $hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $_POST['password'], $salt, $iterations, $length);
                            $hash = strtoupper($hash);

                            $bdd3 = $pdo->query('INSERT INTO users (username, password, mail, account_created, ip_reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$core->F_HTML($_POST['username']), $core->F_HTML($hash), $core->F_HTML($_POST['email']), time(), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]);
                            $_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                            echo 'success';
                        } else {
                            echo 'Passwords does not match.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo 'Password too short.';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Invalid email address.';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'This Email is already used by another account.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid username.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Username already in use.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Required fields are emtpy.';
}
?>
```

And here is my ***login.php*** :

```
<?php
require '../global.php';
$pdo = New Database();
$account->IPisBanned($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$account->isConnected();

if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $bdd = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [$core->F_HTML($_POST['username'])]);


    $iterations = 10000;
    $length = 40;
    $secret = "at_least_16_byte";
    $salt = $secret.$_POST['username'];
    $hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $_POST['password'], $salt, $iterations, $length);
    $hash = strtoupper($hash);


    if($bdd->rowcount() == 1) {

        $req = $bdd->fetch();

        if(password_verify($hash, $req['password'])) {

            $account->UserisBanned($core->F_HTML($_POST['username']));
            $_SESSION['id'] = $req['id'];
            $account->Update($_SESSION['id']);

            echo 'success';

    } else {
            echo 'The password is incorrect.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'The username does not exist.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'The required fields are empty.';
}
?>
```

*I am strongly confused, I spent hours trying to fix this but I really can't.
 Thank you for your time :)*

Comment: The period at the end of `$req = $bdd->fetch();.` seems like a typo, not certain if thats the issue

Comment: I removed it early. I accidentally hit Undo before posting here. Thank you tho :)

Comment: Which error are you getting back specifically?

Comment: The password is incorrect. (i just created many accounts with basic password)

Comment: If you do `var_dump([$hash, $req['password']])`  just before checking the password in login.php, what do you get?

Comment: Also, what does `$core->F_HTML($hash)` do exactly, I see its called when storing the password, but not called when checking the password, could it be changing the saved password somehow?

Comment: it gives me exactly an output of the password hash exactly like in my datase.

Comment: The output of var_dump: `array(2) { [0]=> string(40) "D1585CACD048466A09073C8A0FA49A447BB093DF" [1]=> string(40) "D1585CACD048466A09073C8A0FA49A447BB093DF" } The password is incorrect.`
and adding $core-> does nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that password_verify expects the first param to be the user's **plain text** password.

Try this:

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $req['password'])
```

NOTE: this means you probably need to drop the `strtoupper` as well.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part
>   of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to
>   verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to
>   verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or
>   algorithm information.

```
/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.5.0, PHP 5)<br/>
 *
 * Checks if the given hash matches the given options.
 * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
 * @param string $password The user's password.
 * @param string $hash A hash created by password_hash().
 * @return boolean Returns TRUE if the password and hash match, or FALSE otherwise.
 * @since 5.5.0
 */
function password_verify ($password, $hash) {}
```

### If you dont want to do that, you could drop the `password_verify` and do:

```
`if ($hash === $req['password'])`
```

Comment: Thank you I couldn't use the function properly so I dropped the password_verify. Could it make my website more vulnerable?

Comment: @Dead, not if you continue to use the rest of your code in your question above. Your code without `password_verify` is already doing the same thing `password_verify` would do

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php 
//================================================================
//PBKDF2 generator for PBKDF2 hashed password log in.eg, mosquitto auth-plug
//  I got this generator from somewhere online.. credit go to original writer.. 
//  I research again and again to got loging in Mosquitto server.
//  Use this generator to generate password earlier or use in register.php


 
function password_hash($password, $salt = '', $algo = 'sha256', $iterations = 901, $key_len = 24, $salt_len = 12)
{ 
    //salt len is 12  , ajust your own
    
    
    $salt = 'pN94c3+KCcNvIV1v'; //I added for my own, to use php login. salt is need to be contant all the time
  if($salt=='') $salt = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($salt_len));
  $key = base64_encode(openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, $key_len, $iterations, $algo));
    return sprintf("PBKDF2$%s$%d$%s$%s\n",
                $algo,
                $iterations,
                $salt,
                $key);
}

$password = trim($argv[1]);
if(function_exists('readline'))
{
  while($password=='')
  {
    $password = trim(readline('Enter password: '));
  }
}
else
{
  $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
  while($password=='')
  {
    echo 'Enter password: ';
    $password = trim(fgets($handle));
    echo chr(10);
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

echo 'PBKDF2 password generator for Mosquitto auth plugin [https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug]',chr(10);`enter code here`
echo 'Encoding password = ',$password,chr(10);
echo mqtt_hash($password),chr(10);
?>

//==========================================================================
//  and verify with this pattern in login.php and register php
//  I wrote php script to use above sample function
// php code
<?php
include 'get_hash.php';
$username = $_GET['username'];
$plain_password = $_GET['password'];
$password = trim(get_hash($plain_password)); //trim white space

 $Sql_Query = "select * from tblusers where username = '$username'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        if ($password == $row['pw']){
                    
            $status = "ok";
            
        }
        else
        {
            $status = "failed";  
            
        }
    }
?>


   get_hash.php
    <?php
    // can use login.php and register.php
    function get_hash($password, $salt = '', $algo = 'sha256', $iterations = 901,           $key_len = 24, $salt_len = 12)
    {
      $salt = 'pN94c3+KCcNvIV1v';
     if($salt=='') $salt = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($salt_len));
     $key = base64_encode(openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, $key_len, $iterations,     $algo));
    return sprintf("PBKDF2$%s$%d$%s$%s\n",
                $algo,
                $iterations,
                $salt,
                $key);
}

?>
```